# 2G iPod touch with iOS 4.2.1

Tags: ipod-touch, ios, ipod, pdf

I need a PDF reading app for my 2nd generation iPod touch. I downloaded Adobe Reader, Cloud Readers, iBooks and PDF Reader iPhone edition from the App Store, but all of them require iOS 5.

Please suggest the best PDF reading app for iOS 4.2.1, or suggest some steps to upgrade to iOS 5.

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd generation iPod touch can’t be upgraded to iOS 5.

One PDF reader that still works on pre-iOS 5 devices is [**GoodReader**](http://www.goodiware.com/goodreader.html), although according to their site it requires iOS 4.3.

If you connect your iPod touch to iTunes, then there should be an option to update to iOS 4.3. The instructions in [this Apple Support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4623?viewlocale=fr_fr) explain how to update an iOS 4 device (see **Update your device using iTunes**).

There may be other PDF readers that can run on iOS 4 devices, but I don’t know of any by name. Pre-iOS 5 devices are now a very thin sliver of the iOS installed base, so most developers have dropped support for them.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some I discovered using vintapps 3.1.3:
Advanced PDF Reader,
iPDF,
PDF Word Excel File Viewer,
PdF+,
ReflowPPDF

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, but your iPod cannot upgrade to iOS 4.3.1/5.0.1. Many PDF readers have dropped support now as we'll. Sorry.